# Dropdown quantity option, but only for specific product intervals

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, inventory

We're trying to sell items in packs of 10, but the inventory is managed as individual items, not packs. The client wants users to be able to select their order quantity via a dropdown that only displays multiples of 10. Any idea how to do this? I'm totally lost.

It's set up as a simple product if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to extend the file

app/design/frontend/default/[THEME]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

If this doesnt exist, duplicate path + file from the base folder.

Inside the file, create an if statement based on a product attribute, e.g.

```
<?php if ($_product['attribute']): ?>
```

Then inside the if block, create a drop down box

```
<select name="qty" id="qty">
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```